# Device with no IP address is able to communicate with the network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip-address

I have recently purchased a WiFi infra red hub that can be used to send IR signals to various devices. This is all set up and working fine.

I looked on the router, Fing and viewed the ARP table to try to find the device's IP address, but it doesn't appear anywhere. I've also looked on the router to see if this device is listed.

So, I'm now curious, how is this device communicating with the outside world if it doesn't have an IP address?? Is it able to broadcast to an external IP address via UDP or something with only its MAC address?

The device is branded as Aigoss, and it links to the Tuya Smart Home system.

Using the Tuya app, I can operate IR devices, even when I'm not at home, so it must be connected to the network/internet somehow.

Comment: How did you connect it to your network? How did you link it up with Tuya app? If there were any documentation you followed please link it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer correctly this question you have to be a bit familiar with the OSI model: Read this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_1:_Physical_Layer) page to have an introduction to the OSI model.

I think after you read the layer 2 the answer of your question will be clear:

> **Layer 2**: Data Link Layer The data link layer provides node-to-node data transfer—a link between two directly connected nodes. It detects
>   and possibly corrects errors that may occur in the physical layer. It
>   defines the protocol to establish and terminate a connection between
>   two physically connected devices. It also defines the protocol for
>   flow control between them.
>
> IEEE 802 divides the data link layer into two sublayers:[7]
>
> Medium access control (MAC) layer – responsible for controlling how
>   devices in a network gain access to a medium and permission to
>   transmit data. Logical link control (LLC) layer – responsible for
>   identifying and encapsulating network layer protocols, and controls
>   error checking and frame synchronization. The MAC and LLC layers of
>   IEEE 802 networks such as 802.3 Ethernet, 802.11 Wi-Fi, and 802.15.4
>   ZigBee operate at the data link layer.
>
> The Point-to-Point Protocol (PPP) is a data link layer protocol that
>   can operate over several different physical layers, such as
>   synchronous and asynchronous serial lines.
>
> The ITU-T G.hn standard, which provides high-speed local area
>   networking over existing wires (power lines, phone lines and coaxial
>   cables), includes a complete data link layer that provides both error
>   correction and flow control by means of a selective-repeat
>   sliding-window protocol.

So you can control the IR because (even is wifi or wired connected) they are in the same network and they know the mac address of each other, then communication between the device is possible without an IP address.

I hope this answer clarify your doubt.

---

An update, I read about from your app you can control this IR also from the outside world, this is possible only if the app on your phone connect to the *Tuya Smart Home system* which send the command to the IR.

Comment: If I'm away from my home network (i.e. wifi is turned off on my phone) and I click on one of the virtual remote controls, it still works. This must mean that the 'message' is sent to the Tuya system (from my phone), then it sends a message/command back to my home network, and then onto that device. Is a permanent connection established from the IR hub to the Tuya servers? Or is there some way a 'packet' can be sent to that particular MAC address via my external IP address?

Comment: You have a Tuya hub in the home, a smart gateway right?

Comment: the only "tuya" device is have is the IR device, and it's connected (somehow) to my network.

Comment: can you give a link of IR tech specification?

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07Q568Q9V

Comment: Ok, this device must have an IP Address where to expose is API and receive a command from cloud server, it is not a zigbee device as I though. But layer 2 do not lie :). If you have a linux machine can try to scan your network with nmap I.E. nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24 (change the subnet for your own). Sorry for my misunderstanding of the question

Comment: I had already scanned the network using ARP and looking on the router (and also using an app on my phone called 'fing'), this is where my confusion came from (sorry if I wasn't clear in my question). I'll get my old linux machine out and try doing an nmap

Comment: I've wired up my old linux machine and done an nmap (as above) and it has listed all the devices on the network, but nothing for the IR device. Is it possible it's on a different subnet?

Comment: If that is in a different subnet cannot communicate with the external world trough your router

Comment: could it have some sort of wake-on-lan feature where the wifi chip springs to life when it receives a WOL packet, and then communicates with the server.

Comment: Check also the lease table of your DHCP server on your router, if the device request an ip address there you can find which address is.

Comment: ok, apologies, this is showing on my list of devices. It was using an IP address that was used before by an old device, and the device manufacturer was coming up with something completely unrelated. Sorry if I wasted your time :-(

Comment: No problem at all, the important is figure out the problem :)

Comment: @RichS when reading this comment thread I could not help wondering if this is a "user error".